# Why does GCC fail to optimize unless the return value has a name?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++

Consider this code:

```
#include <array>

class C
{
    std::array<char, 7> a{};
    int b{};
};

C slow()
{
    return {};
}

C fast()
{
    C c;
    return c;
}
```

GCC 6 through 9 produce very bloated code for `slow()`:

```
slow():
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-25], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp-21], 0
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-32], 0
        mov     WORD PTR [rsp-28], ax
        mov     BYTE PTR [rsp-26], 0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-32]
        ret
fast():
        xor     eax, eax
        xor     edx, edx
        ret
```

Is there a difference in meaning between the two functions?  Clang emits code like `fast()` for both, while GCC 4-5 do a better job than 6-9, but not quite optimal either.

Build flags: `-std=c++11 -O3`

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rPNG9o

---

Submitted as a GCC bug based on the feedback here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90883

Comment: To clarify: These results are with optimisation enabled.

Comment: Seems like something you should raise a QoI bug about - not much we can do about it here!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the question is "Is there any difference..." only if the answer is "no" (which is not that obvious at least to me) I would turn to gcc with a QoI bug

Comment: ...maybe add the language-lawyer tag ?

Comment: Check this... https://godbolt.org/z/dxrjn6 remove the ``{}`` from the end of ``a`` and now slow is exactly the same as fast.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 If that's the question then it ought to be framed as such. At the moment it's asking specifically for toolchain-specific implementation details.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much logic to it. Remove ``b`` from the class. If ``a`` has ``{}`` then slow and fast are 2 instructions and identical. If ``a`` has not ``{}`` then slow is two instructions and fast is 12 instructions.  https://godbolt.org/z/88eLqc

Comment: It also seems to compile them the same if you make the members public.  This smells like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: If you remove `{}` from the end of `a`, it is not initialized, so the meaning of the program is not the same (even if the generated code happens to do what we want, we cannot depend on it).

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: You're right, I should have added the language-lawyer tag, as I want to know if I'm mistaken to think that these two functions should or can be optimized the same way.  Doing it now.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: The bad code generation still exists if `C` is a `struct` or has its members `public`.  If you have an example on godbolt.org showing otherwise, please do share it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Looks like it depends on the standard specified.  With C++11 public access doesn't change anything, but with C++17 it makes the two functions compile the same.  [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/YgwqmO)

Comment: I think `return {}` requires padding bits to be set to zero as well, whereas `C c; return c;` does not,  however it doesn't change the code generation go do `C c{}; return c;` instead which is actually equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCC maintainers agreed this was a bug (missed optimization), and it's fixed in trunk for x86_64 (ARM may be fixed later): https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90883

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the complete answer but it might give a clue. As I suspected there is a subtle difference in meaning to `fast` and `slow` which probably sends the compiler down different paths. You can see this if you make the copy constructor private.

https://godbolt.org/z/FMIRe3

```
#include <array>

class C
{
    std::array<char, 7> a{};

    public:
    C(){}

    private:
    C(const C & c){}
};

// Compiles
C slow()
{
    return {};
}

// Does not compile
C fast()
{
    C c;
    return c;
}
```

Even with copy ellision `fast` still requires the copy constructor to be there where as `slow` is returning an `initialization list` which explicitly constructs the return value by the caller. These may or may not end up doing the same thing but I believe the compiler has to do some crunching to determine if this is the case.

There is a detailed blog post that gives some interesting background on this topic

https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2018/05/16/rvalues-redefined/

However the behaviour has changed in C++17

Whereas

```
#include <array>

class C
{
    std::array<char, 7> a{};

    public:
    C(){}

    private:
    C(const C & c){}
};

C slow()
{
    return {};
}

C fast()
{
    return C();
}
```

`fast` would fail to compile under C++11 it now compiles under C++17

https://godbolt.org/z/JG2PkD

The reason is that the meaning of `return C()` changes from returning a temporary to explicitly constructing the object in the frame of the caller.

So now in C++17 there is a big difference between

```
C fast(){
    C c;
    return c;
}
```

and

```
C fast(){
    return C();
}
```

because in the second one you don't even need a copy or move constructor to be available.

https://godbolt.org/z/i2eZnf

Definitely not C++ 101

Comment: Adding `c={};` between the declaration and the return statement in `fast()` makes it produce the same code as `slow()`; thus your intuition about assigning from an `initializer_list` seems to explain this behaviour.

Comment: `return C();` generates the same poor code as `return {};` so it isn't about `initializer_list` per se.

Answer (score 1):

**The two functions are equivalents**: the returned object (more precisely, the result object of an hypothetical call to these functions) is initialized by initializing each member using its default member initializer.

### For  `slow`:

- The pr-value result of the call to slow is copy-inizialized with `{}` as the initializer ([stmt.return](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2.sentence-4))
- so the resulting object is list-initialized ([[dcl.init]/17.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.1));
- which lead us to aggregate-initializion ([[dcl.init.list]/3.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-3.4))

=> so all members of the result object of a call to `slow` are initialized with their default member initializer [dcl.init.aggr]/5.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5.4).

### For `fast`:

- First we assume that copy elision is performed [[class.copy.elision]/1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1.1)
- so the result object of the function call is default initialized [[dcl.init]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#12)
- so the [implicitly declared default constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#1.sentence-2) is called [[dcl.init]/7.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7.1).
- this default constructor is equivalent to `C(){}` ([[class.default.ctor]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#4.sentence-2))

=> so all members of the result object of a call to `slow` are initialized with their default member initializer [[class.base.init]/9.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#9.1)

The **resulting assemblies of the two function are functionally equivalent**. So the assembly produced by Gcc is standard compliant.

In the case of slow, the assembly is just sub-optimal. The object is returned accordingly to the SystemV x86 abi on two registers: rax and rdx (edx). First it zeroes an object conceptualy of class C on the stack at addresses [rsp-32]. It zeroes `a` the padding byte between `a` and `b` and `b`. Then it copies this initialized part of the stack on the registers. The way it zeroes the stack is just suboptimal, and whatsoever all these operations are equivalent to the 2 xor operations of `fast` assembly. So that is just an obvious bug.